# ioinic - Вылетает приложение при openFileDialog на android 4.x

Tags: angularjs, ionic, ionicframework

Добрый день.
Столкнулся с проблемой, что при вызове openDialog вылетает приложение на 4-х андроидах. На двушках вообще не открывается.
Контроллер:

```
$scope.openFileDialog=function() {
    console.log('try to open! $scope.openFileDialog()');
    ionic.trigger('click', { target: document.getElementById('fileRStamp') });
  };

  $scope.addFile = function (newImage) {
    console.log('add file');
    $scope.orderSettings.addStampImages(newImage);
  }
```

Вот кусок визуальной части

```
<div id="page2-markdown1" style="color:#000000;">
    <!--<ion-radio id="page2-radio2" name="file-radio" ng-model="choice" >Прикрепить файл</ion-radio>
    <ion-radio id="page2-radio3" name="file-radio">Сделать снимок</ion-radio>-->

    <!--<span>{{ orderSettings.getStampImages().length }}</span>-->
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item ng-repeat="stampImage in orderSettings.getStampImages() ">
            <a class="item item-thumbnail-left">
                <img  file-preview="stampImage" />
                <h2> {{ stampImage.name }}</h2>
            </a>
        </ion-item>    
    </ion-list>

    <button id="getRStampFile" style="text-align:right;" class="button button-positive  icon-left ion-android-add-circle" ng-click="openFileDialog()">Добавить оттиск</button>
    <input type="file" id="fileRStamp" ng-model="newImage" base-sixty-four-input file-changed hidden />    
</div>
```

по факту основным является

```
<button id="getRStampFile" style="text-align:right;" class="button button-positive  icon-left ion-android-add-circle" ng-click="openFileDialog()">Добавить оттиск</button>
<input type="file" id="fileRStamp" ng-model="newImage" base-sixty-four-input file-changed hidden />
```

5/6 работают нормально. Можете подсказать, что не так с кодом? Вроде бы и инпут есть, и вызов функции. А летит к чертям при запуске на 4.0-4.4.